# ¿Como podría, en un procedimiento sql, realizar esta consulta?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, teradata

quiero realizar un procedimiento SQL en el que tengo una variable tipo int con inicialmente un valor 1. Tengo una tabla con múltiples columnas con el nombre porc_mes_X, donde X es un numero del 1 al 50. Lo que quisiese saber, es como mediante un bucle que vaya aumentando esa variable llamada aux, haga el siguiente select. El valor de perc es fijo:

```
SELECT porc_mes_X
from ea_ter
where porc_mes_X = perc;
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así es como deberías poder ejecutar en un loop aumentando un contador y que vaya llamando a cada uno de esos procedimientos.

```
FOR indice IN 1..50
LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN ' || 'porc_mes_' || indice || '; END;';
END LOOP;
```

La variable indice en este caso no es más que el indice del loop.

Por otra parte vi que mencionas que tenes una tabla con esa info, si esa tabla ya tiene el nombre de cada procedimiento que queres ejecutar entonces podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
FOR row IN ( SELECT porc_mes_X
                from ea_ter
                where porc_mes_X = perc )
LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN ' || row.porc_mes_X || '; END;';
END LOOP;
```

La variable 'row' en este caso reprecenta cada una de las filas que retorna la consulta que pongas dentro del IN. Utilizando la variable row, es muy simple acceder a la info deseada dentro del loop.

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34637529/2336493